# Sphinx: kind of non-strict queries

Tags: full-text-search, sphinx

I have such problem:
for example, we have two items:

1) Bash.org humour - humour from internet users.

2) Ray William Johnson's videos: reviews of humour videos.

When I make a query "humour", I get 1), then 2). When I make query "humour video" I get only 2). When I make query "humour | video", I get 1), then 2), because it's just logical merging of results.

But I need to make some query (not for users, in backend delayed job, so it can be on extended sphinx query language) like "humour video", that gives me 2), then 1), i.e. non-strict results, but sorted by relevance for a phrase.

Ideally, it should allow to make normal queries and such non-strict queries with only one sphinx instance on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a quorum operator: query is '"humour video"/1'